# Check if select box contains a string inside a specific optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's one line in my code that says: "Do something if the select box does not contain an identical option already." At the moment, an option 'Hogwarts' will only be created if there's no school with the same name already in it.

I need this to become "Insert new option if the select box does not contain an identical option *under the same optgroup* already." So if there's already a 'Hogwarts' school inside the 'Hogsmeade' optgroup, I don't want a second one to be created. But if there's another 'Hogwarts' school in Lodon, I want it to appear inside the 'London' optgroup.

```
// Store optgroup in a variable. schoolObject.town is a string such as 'Hogsmeade'.      
$optgroup = $("#schools").find("optgroup[label='" + schoolObject.town + "']");

// schoolObject.name is the name of a school, such as 'Hogwarts'.
// I need to modify the condition in the next line.
if ($("#schools option:contains('" + schoolObject.name + "')").length == 0) {
    // Insert new option
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have a reference to the `optgroup` element, you can then use `find()` to check if an `option` with the specified text exists within it:

```
$optgroup = $("#schools").find("optgroup[label='" + schoolObject.town + "']");
if ($optgroup.find("option:contains('" + schoolObject.name + "')").length == 0) {
    // Insert new option
}
```